# JDK path for Android Studio on Linux

Tags: java, linux, android-studio, java-8, archlinux

I am running Manjaro 17.0.1

I have an issue running **android studio**.

When I run **./studio.sh** I have:

- **A graphical error message from Android Studio saying**

*No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation*

- **A console error message**

  > which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
  >       /usr/bin/dirname: missing operand
  >       Try '/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
  >       /usr/bin/dirname: missing operand
  >       Try '/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
  >       Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------**

I have a directory named /Android in which I have both android studio installation directory and jdk1.8.0_151 directory. I then set **JAVA_HOME** to  point to the jdk directory (/home/myuser/android/jdk1.8.0_151).

I tried to run again android studio and now i get another error message saying

> *./studio.sh: line 207: /home/joub/android/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error*

***EDIT***

***I can not put the jdk directory into /usr/java because i do not have any free space on my disk. This is why I created a new partition and mounted it to /android so I can install both android-studio and JDK inside that directory.***

Comment: Could you type these 2 commands `which java` and `java -version` and edit your question with the results? Seems to me that you have no JDK installed

Comment: I think something is wrong ... !
The output of which java:  
    java not found
The output of java -version:  
    zsh: command not found: java

Comment: you need to install Java. you can find some guides on google. Try these maybe. 
32 bits: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml
 or 64 bits: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml

Comment: I installed it, put it in my /android directory, with the android-studio directory and the jdk one. Still the same error ... Here is a screen : https://www.noelshack.com/2017-50-5-1513351790-error.png

Comment: your JAVA_HOME should be the directory of your jdk folder /home/joub/android/jdk...
Also I think you'd better stick the java directory inside /usr/java/ as suggested on the Oracle site

Comment: Now i set the JAVA HOME to the jdk directory, i have another error : https://www.noelshack.com/2017-50-5-1513356840-azerty.png

Comment: do you have the good version of Java? 32 or 64 bits. Can you do `$ uname -a` to see if your system is 32 or 64

Comment: Here is the output of uname -a: Linux joub-pc 4.9.28-1 MANJARO 1# PREEMPT Sun May 14 20:35:44 UTC 2017 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: This is 32 bits, did you download/install the 32 bit version of Java ? or 64?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your JDK directory here

> /home/myuser/android/jdk1.8.0_151

then set your **JAVA_HOME** to /home/myuser/android/jdk1.8.0_151

Now try

```
$ which java
```

and

```
$ java -version
```

You should have something now.

And try running studio.sh again

Comment: I can not put it there since my primary partition is full (/dev/sda). So i couldn't install android-studio on it. This is the reason why i created a new partition (/dev/sda2) which is mounted on /android. So i have 8gb available on the /android directory to install android studio + to put jdk/jre.