# How to tell react-native which JDK to use among multiple

Tags: java, react-native

I currently have JDK 11 installed in my ubuntu system. I want to start `react-native` development. But I have read that it won't work with any version higher than JDK 8.

So now I would install JDK 8 alongside JDK 11 and set path for it seperately.

So my question is how to command react-native to use JDK 8 only not JDK 11? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can set your environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to what JDK version you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831422/jdk-path-for-android-studio-on-linux

Comment: Thanks, but I won't use android studio. So I am looking for a way to change the configuration of react-native so that it uses jdk8.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use java 11 for react native development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In november 2020, there is no need to downgrade JDK to version 8 for react-native development. You can have JDK 11 as well and it would work perfectly.